# Jira Hotkeys, Is there a way to change status?

Tags: jira

I looked through the hotkeys, and can not find a way of changing the status. This would help me out seeing my timeclock system is integrated in with the "In Progress" status ( I have it set up where if a ticket's status get's put into "In Progress" it clocks that user into that job, And when one moves from "In Progress" to something else, it clocks me out of it )

Comment: One additional bit of information, I primarlly work from the Issue filter screen  , Just in case the page changes the hotkeys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change a tickets status without your hands leaving the keyboard, hit the period (.) key and then type the name of the status you want to transition to. Some JIRA installations or situations may require you to use (gg) instead of (.) so try that too. This will work from the search results screen, agile boards, or just about anywhere where you can select a particular issue.

Be careful to make sure the result that you select shows up under the **Workflow** heading just in case there are other related actions that are worded in a similar fashion to your status.

Comment: Thanks That worked, I tried doing before (.) and then typeing staus and but that only changes the search param status